# Telegram Web Bots data validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, telegram, telegram-bot

I've tried to do user verification script for telegram web app for bots. I have no idea how to fix it.

```
import sha256 from 'js-sha256'

const telegram = window.Telegram.WebApp
const bot_token = '<bot-token>'
const data_check_string = telegram.initData

    var secret_key = sha256.hmac.create(bot_token).update("WebAppData")
    var hash = sha256.hmac.create(data_check_string).update(secret_key).hex();

   if ( hash == telegram.initDataUnsafe.hash) {
       // data is from Telegram
   }
```

Comment: What's your problem? Can you explain it better?

Comment: My code is not working. My hash and hash received from telegram (window.Telegram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe.hash) are different.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look to node js implementation, I tried to well comment it using official telegram pseudocode. Maybe it helps you.

But in my convinience this validation need to execute at backend because in another case you compromise your bot secret token

https://gist.github.com/konstantin24121/49da5d8023532d66cc4db1136435a885

Answer (score 1):

All code samples in internet are not works.
Here is working code for nodejs:

```
import crypto from "crypto";

function auth ( apiToken, telegramInitData ) {
    const initData = new URLSearchParams( telegramInitData );

    initData.sort();

    const hash = initData.get( "hash" );
    initData.delete( "hash" );

    const dataToCheck = [...initData.entries()].map( ( [key, value] ) => key + "=" + value ).join( "\n" );

    const secretKey = crypto.createHmac( "sha256", "WebAppData" ).update( apiToken ).digest();

    const _hash = crypto.createHmac( "sha256", secretKey ).update( dataToCheck ).digest( "hex" );

    return hash === _hash;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The stated code to be used for validation in the official documentation is this:

```
data_check_string = ...
secret_key = HMAC_SHA256(<bot_token>, "WebAppData")
if (hex(HMAC_SHA256(data_check_string, secret_key)) == hash) {
  // data is from Telegram
}
```

please try to implement it as it is documented.

The link referring to this problem is:
[Telegram API validation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-web-app)